# Filter array of dates from 5 minutes gap to 20 minutes gap

Tags: javascript, momentjs, lodash

I have a big array of slots between 08:00-17:00 for a booking application.
Each slot is 5 minutes and i have removed all slots which overlaps an already booked slot.

For example between there 11:00-12:50 there already is an event so this timeslot is not available.

```
{
    "date": "2019-03-15",
    "start": "2019-03-15T09:15:00.000Z",
    "starttime": "10:15",
    "end": "2019-03-15T09:45:00.000Z",
    "endtime": "10:45"
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-03-15",
    "start": "2019-03-15T09:20:00.000Z",
    "starttime": "10:20",
    "end": "2019-03-15T09:50:00.000Z",
    "endtime": "10:50"
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-03-15",
    "start": "2019-03-15T09:25:00.000Z",
    "starttime": "10:25",
    "end": "2019-03-15T09:55:00.000Z",
    "endtime": "10:55"
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-03-15",
    "start": "2019-03-15T09:30:00.000Z",
    "starttime": "10:30",
    "end": "2019-03-15T10:00:00.000Z",
    "endtime": "11:00"
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-03-15",
    "start": "2019-03-15T11:50:00.000Z",
    "starttime": "12:50",
    "end": "2019-03-15T12:20:00.000Z",
    "endtime": "13:20"
  },
```

However, before i return it to the enduser i need to remove all elements so there is a 20 minutes gap between every slot.
So instead of slots every 5 minutes i want them to have a 20 minutes gap. So the endtime must be 10:20... 10:40... 11:00..
All events must not have a gap to an already booked event.
So every slot must have a slot which connects to an existing event.

How am i supposed to do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO, to round a date to the nearest 20 minute slot you can do the following: `new Date(d.getTime()+(((d.getMinutes()%20)-10)*60000))`  where `d` is a valid Date object. You can use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to convert all the dates. To remove overlapping will get more complicated. What would you like to do if one appointment is for the entire day? Do you want to remove all other appointments?

Answer (score 0):

Put the  Json object in a array  and execute the following code.

Where search is the varible used to find the timeslot.

```
function toDate(dStr,format) {
    var now = new Date();
    if (format == "h:m") {
        now.setHours(dStr.substr(0,dStr.indexOf(":")));
        now.setMinutes(dStr.substr(dStr.indexOf(":")+1));
        now.setSeconds(0);
        return now;
    }else 
        return "Invalid Format";
}

let serach="13:10";
let value = sample.filter((val) => {
    if( (toDate(val.endtime,"h:m").toTimeString() >= toDate(serach,"h:m").toTimeString()) && (toDate(val.starttime,"h:m").toTimeString() <= toDate(serach,"h:m").toTimeString()) ){
      return val.starttime;
   }
})
```

value will hold the array which has the timeslot matched with the date in json